# How many teams can be formed?

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to calculate the number of choices of teams I can make in the following scenario.

Suppose a team is comprised of 3 characters (1 leader and 2 support members) and suppose there are 108 characters in total that can play. How many different team combinations would there be?

My attempt at the problem is that it would be 108 choose 3, but I'm being thrown off since I don't know how to alter my calculation to incorporate the fact that there is a leader and two supports in a team (if this matters?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose any $3$ persons and then pick the leader among them, which by the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) gives a total of $$\dbinom{108}{3}\dbinom{3}{1}=\frac{108!}{3!105!}\cdot\frac{3!}{2!1!}=\frac{108\cdot107\cdot106}{2}$$ ways. Equivalently stated: each group of $3$ persons, there are $\dbinom{108}{3}$ such groups, can "produce" $3$ different teams, one possibility for each different person being the leader, hence multiplication with the term $\dbinom{3}{1}=3$.

---

**Edit:** According to the multiplication principle we can split the process of the formation of the teams in several steps (here $2$ steps) and calculate the total number of the teams that can be formed as the product of the possibilities of conducting each step. Here $\dbinom{108}{3}$ for the first step (to choose $3$ persons) times $\dbinom{3}{1}=3$ possibilities to choose a leader among them (second and final step).

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by the multiplication principle?

Comment: @Uchu Yes, see my edit.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, if instead of 3 person teams, I had a 2 person team with one leader and one support, would I be right in saying that the number of choices of teams would be 108 choose 2 multiplied by 2 choose 1?

Comment: @Uchu Yes, it would be correct, you understand correctly.